# Confuse query add date not in table for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

excuse me,
i will add date if that date not in table on mysql
example i have table

```
ID      |   name    |   date        |   clock in    |   clock out
---------------------------------------------------------------
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-18  |   09:40       |   17:15
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-20  |   08:20       |   17:35
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-21  |   08:40       |   17:40
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-23  |   08:10       |   17:50
```

so, how to add date in to no table and set clock in and clock out set null
example

```
ID      |   name    |   date        |   clock in    |   clock out
---------------------------------------------------------------
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-18  |   09:40       |   17:15
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-19  |   null        |   null
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-20  |   08:40       |   17:40
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-21  |   08:10       |   17:50
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-22  |   null        |   null
1001    |   A       |   2013-09-23  |   08:10       |   17:50
```

thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: you dont have to do this and fill your database , you can select dates which are not in table

Comment: what you want to say i am unable to understand

Comment: im, sorry. i will create database attendance

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need if you're still interested:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(id,1001) id,
COALESCE(name,'A') name,
fixed_days.fixed_date,
clockin,clockout
FROM t 
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT CURDATE() as fixed_date 
UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day 
UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 day 
UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 day 
UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 day 
UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 day 
UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 day) AS fixed_days 
ON t.record_date = fixed_days.fixed_date
WHERE fixed_days.fixed_date <= (select max(record_date) from t);
```

**[SQL Fiddle..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3b1ec/1/0)**